# Why solutions of Lotka-Volterra model are cycles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I need to analyze Lotka-Volterra model, I have everything except the fact that curves around $(\frac{a}{b},\frac{d}{c})$ are closed, I found one proff in internet, but i don't understand it. 
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=N(a-b\cdot P)$$
$$\frac{dP}{dt}=P(c\cdot N-d)$$
I will be very glad for as simple as possible explanation.

Comment: "I found one pro(o)f (o)n (the) internet, but (I) don't understand it" This (the proof and why you do not understand it) is what should be in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Compute
$$
\frac{\dot N}{N}(cN−d) - \frac{\dot P}{P}(a−bP)
=(a−bP)(cN−d)-(cN−d)(a−bP)=0
$$
As this expression is of the form $f'(N)\dot N+g'(P)\dot P=0$, one can directly integrate to obtain $f(N)+g(P)=C$,
$$
cN-d\ln|N|-a\ln|P|+bP=C.
$$

As this is a first integral of the differential equation, all solution curves follow the level sets of this function. As the level sets are compact, the solution curves are closed.